# Off Topic Wording

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When a question is closed as offtopic, because it relies on a 3rd party plugin or theme, the text of the close message is clear.

However recently someone asked a question about why their site didn't show up in Google. As this was about a 3rd party service, it fits into that close reason, but the message doesn't state 3rd party services.

Should we change the wording accordingly?

Comment: Imo: Yes. But we could talk about close voting policy as well. I'm open for that discussion.

Comment: @kaiser I think that will be a good discussion to open on meta. That is what meta is for afterall. It will be good to get new ideas, revisit old ones and make necesssar changes to make the policies and closed messages clearer. It will really not hurt reviewing our close vote policy. I think that is one area that we do get some stick on from new commers. Got some stick from guy yesterday telling me I was not helpful and hinted that I'm rude because I told him his question was off topic and directed him to check out the help and ask sections. Doesn't bother me, but it is annoying :-)

Comment: Tom, do you really think that message is clear. The third party part is added in a kind of *BTW* mood. Many users whos questions get closed come back and tell you their question is specific to wordpress, and you tell them about the third party part, they hit back with the wordpress part. Just a suggestion, can't we separate the generic section from the third party section and let each have its own flag. CSS, php and jquery specific questions can be flagged as such (generic flag) and then plugin/theme specifc questions can be flagged as such (third party flag) :-)

Comment: Pieter, we dont have endless reasons available. 5 is the threshold.

Comment: @kaiser that is a bit of a bummer but nothing we can do about it :-) Would have been nice to separate those. *Separation of concern* ;-)